# using if empty()

Tags: php

I've website and for unknown reason i'm getting per minute more than 200 spamming post
and yet i still not need to use captcha

I've got an idea since my attacking bots are hungry for any input form is by creation the following

1- Browser hidden text input

```html
<style>
    .comment {visibility: hidden;}
</style>
<input name="comment" id="comment" type="text" class="comment" />
```

2- using php if it empty then no spam bot and if not empty then it must be spam bot
but the php code gives me error as it looks not working

```php
$comment = $_POST[comment];
    
if( !empty($comment) ) {
    echo "you are bot right then die go to hell";
} else {
    echo "fine";
}
```

for unknown reason to me that php code not working ! i'm not sure about `empty()` how to use it.

Comment: You should use directly `if(empty($_POST['comment']))` (don't forget `'`) for case that `$_POST['comment']` isn't set.

Comment: you are or are not using a captcha? if not why?

Comment: Are users unable to post? Or do bot came trough? Maybe your form is already cached, try to change input names.

Comment: @Dagon my website is for young kids , they can draw and save their drawing sharing it replace it ...etc so captcha is very annoying.

Comment: @Vyktor the bots are posting ads and they came from one website is world wide known spam support , i don't know if i'm allowed to post URL or not but here is it UU UU UU formspring dot me , I've report it many times and they no way.

Comment: more annoying than 200 spam a minute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you are missing the quotes around 'comment'

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
if( $comment !== null && strlen($comment) > 0 )
{ 
  //dangerrrrrrrrr, be very afraid.
} else {
  //business as usual
}
```

Comment: They're missing, but it will actually work anyway.  PHP will interpret is a constant `comment` but since the constant is unknown it will assume you meant the string `'comment'` and add the quotes itself, while throwing a Warning.

Comment: works perfect, looks like i'm having good surprise to the bots this nigh :) nihaaaaa nihaaaaa thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
$comment=isset($_POST['comment']) ? (!empty($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : null) : null ;
if($comment)
{ 
    //comment available
}
else
{
    //comment not available
}
```